# Sum of two kronecker products as a kronecker product

Tags: linear-algebra, kronecker-product

I seek for the following relationship (if there is one so):

$$C \otimes D = (A_1 \otimes B_1) + (A_2 \otimes B_2)$$

I would like to obtain $C = f(A_1,A_2)$ (in terms of $A$'s) and $D = g(B_1,B_2)$ (in terms of $B$'s). For simplicity, we can assume $A_i$ and $B_i$ are covariance matrices, so positive-definite, square, and symmetric.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

PS: For more simplification (if so), we can assume $\dim(A_1) = \dim(A_2)$ and same for $B_i$'s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $A=A_1\otimes B_1+ A_2\otimes B_2=C\otimes D$.

Let $F(A)=Id\otimes tr(\cdot)(A)=Ctr(D)=A_1tr(B_1)+A_2tr(B_2)$ and

$G(A)=tr(\cdot)\otimes Id(A)=Dtr(C)=B_1tr(A_1)+B_2tr(A_2)$.

Notice that $tr(A)\neq 0$, because $0\neq A$ is a positive semidefinite symmetric matrix. Observe that $tr(A)=tr(C)tr(D)$.

So $A=C\otimes D= \frac{1}{tr(C)tr(D)}F(A)\otimes G(A)=\frac{1}{tr(A)}F(A)\otimes G(A)$.

Thus, if $tr(A)\neq 0$ then $A=C\otimes D$ iff $A=\frac{1}{tr(A)}F(A)\otimes G(A)$.

Comment: Hi, I am a little confused by this answer and was wondering if you could provide some clarity. What does $tr(\cdot)$ mean here? (I.e. what is it the trace of?) I am a little confused by your first step and am trying to do something similar to this question and don't want to repeat the question on stack exchange.

Comment: @JDoe2 $tr(\cdot)$ stands for the trace. So $Id\otimes tr(\cdot)$ is the trace acting only on the matrices of the right side of the tensor.

Comment: Hmm so $F(A)=Id \otimes tr(A)$ then? Why does this equal $Ctr(D)$ and not $Id \otimes tr(C) tr(D)$?

Comment: @JDoe2 Define  $F:M_k\otimes M_m \rightarrow M_k$ as $F(\sum_{i=1}^mC_i\otimes D_i)=\sum_{i=1}^mC_itr(D_i)$. So $F(C\otimes D)=C tr(D)$. This is commonly known as  the "partial trace" on the right side (Check wikipedia's page).  Note that if $C\otimes D$ is the Kronecker product of $C$ and $D$ then $tr(C)tr(D)=tr(C\otimes D)$ which is the "total trace".

Comment: I see thank you!

Comment: This is nice! Can you please provide some reference for this result?

Comment: @rmm93  F,G are  usually called the partial traces. Check this reference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_trace

Comment: Can the result be modified to obtain the kronecker decomposition of general matrices in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ ?

Comment: @rmm93. Define $Vec:\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$, as the column vector $Vec(X)=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)^t$, where $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ are the rows of $X$. Let $F(\sum_{i}A_i\otimes B_i)=\sum_{i} Vec(A_i)Vec(B_i)^t$.                        
Since the rank of a matrix  can be defined as the minimum number of outer products that must be added to form the matrix then the rank of the tensor $\sum_{i}A_i\otimes B_i$ is the rank of the matrix $\sum_{i} Vec(A_i)Vec(B_i)^t$.

Comment: @rmm93 If you want to know whether $\sum_{i}A_i\otimes B_i$ has tensor rank 1, i.e. $\sum_{i}A_i\otimes B_i=C\otimes D$, you just need to check whether $\sum_{i}Vec(A_i)Vec(B_i)^t$ has rank 1.

Answer (score 2):

If
$$
C \otimes D = (A_1 \otimes B_1) + (A_2 \otimes B_2),
$$
then $A_1$ and $A_2$ are linearly dependent and so are $B_1$ and $B_2$.
If $A_1$ and $B_1$ are nonzero, then
$$
C \otimes D = \lambda(A_1 \otimes B_1)
$$
for some $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ and so $C=\mu A_1$ and $D=\frac\lambda\mu B_1$ for any $\mu\neq0$.
You cannot determine $C$ and $D$ uniquely from $C\otimes D$ since you always have the freedom to scale one up and the other one down.

Comment: thanks! Actually I have $(A_1\otimes B_1) + (A_2 \otimes B_2)$ and want to come up with such a representation. Your answer starts with this, so if there is such a representation, then they are linearly dependent (right?). But if we don't know but want to come up with such a representation, I think we can not assume linear dependence. Is that right? so what are the conditions of existence?

Comment: @oeda, If there is such a representation for $C\otimes D$, then we have linear dependence. And if the $A$s and $B$s are linearly dependent, we can always find $C$ and $D$. If you don't want the sum of the tensor products to be a tensor product, it suffices to assume that $A$s and $B$s are linearly independent.

Comment: Thank you. Matrices are square symmetric and pos. def., and of same size (A and B's). But I can't directly say anything about their dependence.