# Sum of Kronecker Products, $(\mathbf I_n\otimes\mathbf I_m)+(\mathbf A\otimes \mathbf B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, kronecker-product

Suppose $\mathbf A$ is $n\times n$ and $\mathbf B$ is $m\times m$. Is it possible to write
$$ (\mathbf I_n\otimes\mathbf I_m)+(\mathbf A\otimes \mathbf B)$$
as a Kronecker product between two matrices?

Obs.: The answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1349093/287326) is not exactly applicable, but seems to be related.

Comment: Isn't $I\otimes I=I$?

Comment: Yes, in this case $(\mathbf I_n \otimes \mathbf I_m)=\mathbf I_{nm}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1349096/51744) to the question you cited, the equation:
$$
  C\otimes D = I_n\otimes I_m + A\otimes B
$$
where $C$ and $D$ are unknowns, admits solutions iff $A=\lambda I_n$ and $B=\mu I_m$.

Comment: I understood it as saying that it admits a **unique** solution iff these conditions hold.

Comment: But I think I was wrong before, the other answer to the question does appear to be applicable. Thank you for your help.

Comment: It admits an infinity of solutions; there is clearly a degree of freedom in the relative scale of $C$ and $D$.